# heimcontrol.js Node/Mongodb: 'events.js:2817: Uncaught Error: Cannot open /dev/'

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, motion

I have been struggling for a week trying to figure out what went wrong. I had this running fine from outside my house and controlling an led on a breadboard. When I restarted my pi and attempted to run 'node heimcontrol.js', I am greeted with 'info - socket.io started' (expected), and two instances of 'events.js:2817: Uncaught Error: Cannot open /dev/' and no return of listening on port. I've checked and changed my permissions of /dev/ to 'drwxr-xr-x 12 pi root 3100 Sep 28 15:58 dev'. I know 777 isn't the best practice, but I was trying to see if that was the issue. I've tried to locate the events.js to dig deeper, but no luck. What should I check next? I've run out of ideas.

node v0.10.2
mongo v2.1.1

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/heimcontrol.js $ node heimcontrol.js
    info  - socket.io started
events.js:2817: Uncaught Error: Cannot open /dev/
events.js:2817: Uncaught Error: Cannot open /dev/
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Edit 01: I pointed my Pi browser to 127.0.0.1:8080 and was greeted with a page 'Motion 3.2.12 Running [1] Threads' and a hyperlink 'All' which leads to settings. I am assuming that I created a video module in Heimcontrol and did not finish the setup since Motion detect my camera (RPi camera module). Not familiar with Motion, maybe someone can help guide me.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out as I am having the exact same problem..

Comment: I did not, and haven't gone back to working with Heimcontrol. Here is the issue that I raised on the github. Maybe if you add a comment, they might take another look at it.

https://github.com/ni-c/heimcontrol.js/issues/12